# How to access all historical public posts of user?

Tags: stocktwits

I am writing a script that will extract all posted entries and exits for EOD & EOW performance reporting. I would also like to start out by generating a report for all historical trades. Is there a simple way to retrieve all the message history of a single user?

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently offer historical data, aside from the ability to request messages with a maximum message_id.  Our data vendors do offer historical data, and we may in the future offer it ourselves if we find enough interest.